# Finding a regex for ipv6 address range

Tags: regex, ip, ipv6

I need a regular expression for ipv6 addresses with the following mask :
2620:0000:2820::/48

That is I want an regex which can represent the following range of addresses:

```
2620:0000:2820:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000
```

TO

```
2620:0000:2820:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

So far I could come up with this :

```
"^(2620:0000:2820:){1}:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}$"
```

What is the correct expression ?

Comment: Whats wrong with what you got?

Comment: Just change `{4}` to `{1,4}`

Comment: "If you learned how to use hammer, then every problem looks like a nail". You should not do that - you will always miss something. For example, you will miss this: `2620:0000:2820:0000::0000:0000` and this: `2620:0000:2820:ffff::0000` and who knows what else. Correct solution is to convert IPv6 into internal representation and work with bits

Answer (score 0):

How about this Regex:-

```
'/^(?>(?>([a-f0-9]{1,4})(?>:(?1)){7}|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9](?>:|$)){8,})((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,6})?::(?2)?)|(?>(?>(?1)(?>:(?1)){5}:|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){6,})(?3)?::(?>((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,4}):)?)?(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(?>\.(?4)){3}))$/iD'
```

Also check this [reference](http://vernon.mauery.com/content/projects/linux/ipv6_regex).

Comment: I would suspect this kind of regex in that the need for lookahead's should not be necessary. The compilation should result in a disambiguous pass or fail without that need.